# Is it possible to evenly distribute table columns who's width is equal to its content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was wondering if it's possible to evenly distribute the columns of a table, when the width of the columns is fit to the content.

My table has either 3 or 4 columns. The content of the columns is dynamic so could grow with different data. It's mostly one single column that will contain large amounts of data though.

Consider the following three example tables:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to have the content of the first column start at the far most left and the content of the last column end at the far most right.
The remaning content should be evenly distributed across the table.

I've tried creating the same result with flexbox div in stead of a table, however. That worked for evenly distributing the content, however, I was not able to create the black border at the bottom of the table heads.

The content off the example table should evenly distribute as is done in the screenshot sketch.

[image: sketch column distribution]

**How would I go about distributing table columns based on it's content?**

*[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qjx9wceh/1/)*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried width = "100%" ?

```
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th width="200px">Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th width="200px">This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th width="200px">Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Based on your fiddle :

Try to add a fixed width in end of last-child :

```
  &:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 200px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qjx9wceh/6/

Answer (score 0):

Set the followings.

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;

} 
table td {
   width:1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the table's `width` to `100%`

Also set the table's `layout` property to `fixed`
The properties are

> table-layout: auto|fixed|initial|inherit;

Reference link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

The updated fiddle of yours -> https://jsfiddle.net/qjx9wceh/4/

```css
table
{
width:100%; 
table-layout:fixed; 
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124, 213, 124</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 1</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> of blok 2</th>
      <th>This is the title for<br> of blok 3</th>
      <th>Title blok<br> last block</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>213</td>
      <td>€ 200.000</td>
      <td>XQABBBBQQVVVSS1234567 X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not address the fact that the whitespace should be even among the content, not the collumns itself (as you can see from the purple arrows in the screenshot). This also does not address the fact that the most right content 
should end at the far most right border of the table as it is in the screenshot.

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle link I've attached

Comment: The number of columns will be automatically split into same equal widths (Use browser inspector to inspect the elements)

Comment: I did check the jsfiddle, it does not match the image with the required result. The collumns are equal width and evenly distributed but this is not the required result. The required result is that the content of those collumns are evenly distributed and have the same amound of white-space between them.

Comment: That's not possible since the data is dynamic. If it's not possible with pure html/css a javascript sollution would be acceptable though not preferred.

Comment: @JunRikson If you think my question is not clear in any way, feel free to edit it or ask for clarifications.